# Auto adjust height size,according to window size,and make the button fill the space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my site responsive, so at first I made the font size and the sticky top bar's height adjust to the window size, the result was as follows:

- The font size did change indeed,but went too small that at some point,i had a little space under the buttons,that wasn't filled with the button,that is something i need to fix.
- The top bar's height isn't adjusting, maybe I did a maths miscalculation, but I need some help with it.

Please note that I uploaded only the useful CSS code

This is my CSS:

```css
#bar {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    max-height:50px;
    background-color: #595959;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
    z-index:9999;
}

.bar-fixed {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#bar nav {
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
}

#bar nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #595959;
}

#bar nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#bar nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    color:  #e6e6e6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#bar nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#bar nav ul ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #595959;
}

#bar nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

#bar nav ul ul li a{
    display: block;
    color:  #e6e6e6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;  
}

#bar nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background-color:black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

html { font-size: 90.5%; }

body {
    padding: 0px;margin:0px;font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="topsec">
  <div id="bar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
      <ul >
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="main">
  </article>
  <aside class="aside LB"></aside>
  <aside class="aside RB"></aside>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</div>
```

This my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 59) {
      $('#bar').addClass('bar-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 60) {
      $('#bar').removeClass('bar-fixed');
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  var holdWidth = $(window).width();
  var holdHeight = $(window).height();
  var holdAverageSize = (holdWidth + holdHeight) / 2;
  $(window).on('resize', function () {
    newAverageSize = ($(window).width() + $(window).height()) / 2;
    newPercentage = ((newAverageSize / holdAverageSize) * 100) + "%";
    $("html").css("font-size", newPercentage)
    $("#bar").css("height", newPercentage) /* am pretty sure this couldn't work because i am assigning a % to a porperty i a already set with px */
    console.log(newPercentage);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(document).height()` and `$(document).width()`. I think this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your second point:

In the rules for '#bar' you have both `height: 50px;` *and* `max-height:50px;` (which is redundant, since `height` is already fixed at 50px).

So obviuosly somewhere you have media queries / another rule for '#bar' at another viewport width. If that second rule includes only either `height` *or* `min-height` (and if it's called *after* the rule shown in your question), this will still leave the other (not included) parameter at the value from *this* rule.

EDIT: For example the responsive rule might contain `max-height: 30px`, but since there's still `height: 50px` in the general rule, `#bar` will remain 50 pixels high. That could be the cause for your header not adjusting height.

So you'd have to list both of them, and for example include `max-height: none;` or `height: auto;` to "neutralize" them.

Comment: for the double height property,it's because i had a problem when i resized the window into a smaller one,the mid section went higher in order to contain all the content(this was before i made the font size adjustable,i obviously forgot to change it)
considering the media queries,it does exist,but doesnt concern any of the heights